# File Upload not showing in swagger (Nest JS)

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have implemented a file upload function along other data , wanted to try out the api in swagger but it does not show the file upload modal.
My controller file is as follows :

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  @Put()
  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Endpoint used to update values in the checklist Template',
  })
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  async updateChecklistTemplate(
    @Body() setFieldValueDto: UpdateChecklistValueDto,
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Request() req,
    
  ) {
    return await this.checklistTemplatesService.setFieldValue(
      setFieldValueDto,
      req.user.id,
      file,
    );
  }
```

My DTO file :

```
import {
  IsArray,
  IsBoolean,
  IsMongoId,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsOptional,
  IsString,
} from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
export class UpdateChecklistValueDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsMongoId()
  readonly id: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsBoolean()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly isImage: boolean;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly entity: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly value: string;

  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'binary', required: true })
  file: Express.Multer.File;
}
```

I am kind of new to this, appreciate it if you could point out anything missing here.
Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@ApiConsumes` and `@ApiBody` decorators. See the NestJS documentation for [File uploads](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/operations#file-upload). Your case might look something like this but please also check the [swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) to customise based on your specific requirements

```
import { ApiBody, ApiConsumes } from '@nestjs/swagger';
...
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
@Put()
@ApiOperation({
  summary: 'Endpoint used to update values in the checklist Template',
})
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
@ApiBody({
  schema: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      file: {      <----- matches the string in FileInterceptor('file')
        type: 'string',
        format: 'binary',
      },
    },
  },
})
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
async updateChecklistTemplate(
```

The nestjs docs suggest usage like this:

```
@ApiBody({
  description: 'List of cats',
  type: FileUploadDto,
})

// Where FileUploadDto is defined as follows:

class FileUploadDto {
  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'binary', required: true })
  file: any;
}

// Your case
export class UpdateChecklistValueDto extends FileUploadDto {
...
}
```

With this many decorators for one route, you could create a custom decorator to handle the file upload like so:

```
const ApiFile =
  (fileName: string = 'file'): MethodDecorator =>
  (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    ApiBody({
      schema: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          [fileName]: {
            type: 'string',
            format: 'binary',
            required: true,
          },
        },
      },
    })(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
  };

export function SingleFile(fileName?: string) {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data'),
    ApiFile(fileName),
    UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file')),
  );
}

// Your controller route
@SingleFile()
@Put()
@ApiOperation({
  summary: 'Endpoint used to update values in the checklist Template',
})
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
async updateChecklistTemplate(
```

Comment: This is indeed what the doc is saying, but I don't see the modal either, only `file: string($binary)` literally displayed in the interface. I'm using `@nestjs/swagger` v6.2.1, it might be a regression.